# what happened to old images?

Tags: support

In [this Q](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10971/work-around-arcgis-image-server-export-limit) the image it used to have has been replaced with "the image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available (imgur.com)". This isn't the first time I've seen this. Previously I just fixed the post by uploading a new pic because I remembered what it was (and still had it or something similar). I can't do that this time. Is the old image recoverable or moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

From the [http://imgur.com/faq](https://imgur.com/faq)

> As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they
>   will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to
>   create more space for newer images.

Although as your question was from June this can't be the case here. Did you upload the first image? I presume if you did you didn't request its removal.

It's worrying if images are going missing for future viewers of the question.

Comment: Maybe SE could program the Community user to view images referenced by gis.SE at least every 6 mo.

Comment: Does this rule apply to the StackExchange's [arrangement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) with imgur though?

Comment: yes I uploaded the original

Answer (score 4):

I discovered how to fix the image link: change `i.stack.imgr.com` to `i.imgr.com` ([see history](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/10971/revisions) > markdown diff).

[image: markdown diff screenshot]

Comment: Looks like there was a dedicated server/domain which is now lost? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com

Answer (score 1):

A commenter said that an image I had just uploaded as part of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/why-does-my-arcmap-10-export-circles-instead-of-diamonds/16786#16786) was not showing up either. Is this the case for anyone else, and what is going on?

Comment: False alarm, I guess, sounds like it was just the one commenter's browser version or work environment.